# Python Flask and Nginx-> routes redirection

Tags: python, nginx, flask, server, flask-admin

I have an app, built with Flask-User and Flask-Login. This app is working.
I launch my app like :

```
app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```

This app is running into a container, which is linking ports like XXXX:5000

My problem is that : On my server, I'm running my container. On this server, I also use nginx where I set a special url for this porject. The special url is : '/my_special_url'

The problem is that I can't redirect my app endpoints (like '/sign_up' or '/register') to the right urls defined by nginx (it must be '/my_special_url/sign_up' or '/my_special_url/register').

I tried to use url_prefix into the flask app, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want url redirection in nginx or url parsing in flask?

Comment: I use this : https://gist.github.com/Larivact/1ee3bad0e53b2e2c4e40

Comment: Did you try request.url as suggested?